# Installing Texlive on Debian x86-64 Platform

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

I had previously worked with the texlive distribution provided in the Debian repository, but I came across many inconveniences as a result of it being outdated (no tlmgr; forced to manually update and install packages, etc.) So I decided to remove the package and reinstall texlive using the installer provided by the CTAN website.

After waiting several hours for it install all the packages, `latex` does not seem to recognize any of the new packages that should have come with the 2011 texlive distribution (e.g. `adforn`). Furthermore, `tlmgr` did not show up as a recognized command. So I try

```
cd /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/
sudo ./tlmgr --self --update all
```

But the operation fails, with the following output.

```
tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
Fundamental package texlive.infra not present, uh oh, goodbyeSerious error, texlive.infra not found at ./tlmgr line 4949.
```

I have not been able to find much useful information online regarding the error message. Do you have any ideas as to how I can fix `tlmgr` and get `latex` to recognize the newly-installed packages?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It sounds like your distribution belongs to `root` at the moment. If you want to keep it that way, then you can run `tlmgr` by following [http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-998739.html](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-998739.html). If you want to change the ownership, then you can use `sudo chown -R <yourusername> /usr/local/texlive/2011`. Of course, you also need to make sure that you update the `PATH` using `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH `

Comment: Note that TL2011 is in `unstable`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, your problem is that
/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/
is not in the path. Try

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/":$PATH"
```

---

I normally install texlive as follows (Debian wheezy amd64):

As root

```
mkdir /opt/texlive
chown <user>.<group> /opt/texlive
```

As user, run install-tl and follow the normal installlation procedure.

Add

```
TEXLIVE="/opt/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux"
export PATH=$TEXLIVE":$PATH"
```

somewhere at the end of your ~/.bashrc file

This method allows you to install texlive without intefering with the debian texlive packages.

Comment: This answer was the closest to the solution that I just took to fix the problem. I had to run `sudo apt-get purge texlive*` to completely remove the Debian installation, and then rerun `tl-installer` to reinstall. After that, I did `cd /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/` and `chmod +x *`. Finally, I added the path to my `.bashrc` profile. I assumed that the installer would take care of a lot of this.

Comment: Running `apt-get purge texlive*` was useless: adding `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux` at the _beginning_ of your `PATH` would have been enough. I'd be *very* surprised that the `chown +x` was needed too. Also, the TL installer prints a message suggesting that you add TL to your path, but can't do it itself since there are so many different ways to do it depending on your distribution, your shell and/or desktop environment, whether you're the only user or not, etc.

Comment: Yes, but `apt-get purge` was necessary in order to remove many of the files remaining from the Debian texlive distribution; `autoremove` did not manage to remove them. I actually added `/usr/.../x86_64-linux/` to `PATH` before running tl-installer the first time, but the installation failed as reported.

Comment: "somewhere at the end of your ~/.bashrc file". Actually, I had better results (compatibility with Krunner, auctex, to name a few) by editing `/etc/profile`, by adding `:/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux` at the end of the declaration of my `PATH` variable.