# Upgrading Tex Live from 2013 to 2015 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, paths

I upgraded `Tex Live` from `2013` to `2015` on `Ubuntu 14.04` using the guidelines given [in this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/4821). But have some problems. After upgrading when I check the version of `Tex Live` using `tex --version` command it gives the the following information:

```
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

However, after changing the PATH (as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52401/4821)) through:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux/":$PATH"
```

if I check the version of `Tex Live` using `tex --version` command it gives the the following information:

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

But after closing the terminal, the `PATH` again reset to original `PATH` and show the `TeX Live 2013 version`. I would highly appreciate if someone help me figure out this problem and have to delete `Tex Live 2013`. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edited**

```
yaseen@yaseen:~$ /etc/environment
bash: /etc/environment: Permission denied
yaseen@yaseen:~$ ~/.profile
bash: /home/yaseen/.profile: Permission denied
yaseen@yaseen:~$ ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/yaseen/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

Contents of `sudo gedit ~/.profile`

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: You probably set the path somewhere else. What do you have in /etc/environment ? What about ~/.profile ? What about ~/.bashrc ?

Comment: you just need to set your PATH somewhere that persists, this is nothing to do with tex, just standard unix, eg .profile or .login or .bash_profile according to your setup

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for your interest in my problem. Actually I'm new to Ubuntu and would appreciate if you help me to figure out this problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty for showing interest in my problem. Please my edits.

Comment: You need to edit those files just like you would a `.tex` file.  Try the command `<editor> ~/.profile`, where `<editor>` is your favourite text editor (e.g., `emacs` or `gedit` or `nano` or -- dare I say it? -- `vi`).  Note that you need administrator powers for `/etc/environment`, so you'd do something like `sudo emacs /etc/environment` if you want to go there.  (I use `~/.profile`, personally.)

Comment: Or to just see the contents try `cat file`, e.g. `cat ~/.bashrc`. They are just text files, so running them makes no sense.

Comment: @jon, what edits I have to make?

Comment: @MYaseen208 open the files with your favorite text editor, then search for "PATH". This is just to find out where the PATH is being set to 2013. The next step, once you find it, is to change it to the 2015 path.

Comment: @scottkosty: Please see the contents of `sudo gedit ~/.profile` and guide me accordingly. Sorry for bothering you again and again for such small this but this is a very serious problem for me.

Comment: Do not use `sudo` for files in your HOME directory (= `~/` = `/home/<user>/`. You should just use `gedit ~/.profile` as I wrote. I'm still using TL 2014, but you probably want: to add the line: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux/:$PATH` at the end of the file `.profile`.

Comment: Then also: `MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH` and 
`INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH`.  (But I'm not on 2015 yet, so you should check.).  Then, to apprise your session of the changes, `source  ~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just typed the `export PATH=...` into the console.

Write this into your `~/.profile` and check after you opened a new console.

Comment: Did you read the comments? You do not think it is important to find out where TeX Live 2013 is added to the PATH?